# How to separate two numbers in the same column

Tags: string, excel, helper, ice, vba

I'm trying to extract the numbers on the right e.g 1.25 in the first row (below).

```
AQ2 1.1.25
AQ3 1.2.15
AQ4 1.2.25
AQ5 1.1.44
AQ6 1.1.60
```

From AQ2-6
SOLVED using excel wizard

Comment: The RIGHT function's second parameter is the number of characters, counting from the right. If all of numbers have the form n.nn, then Right(AQ,4) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Right(A1, 4)`

or you can use text to column editor also where you can put `.` as breaking point.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more suited to SuperUser.
I'll give a formula answer and a code answer to return everything to the right of the first point:
`=MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,LEN(A1))`

Returns `#Value!` if the there's no `.` in Target:

```
Public Function AQNumber(Target As Range) As Variant

    If InStr(Target, ".") > 0 Then
        AQNumber = Mid(Target, InStr(Target, ".") + 1)
    Else
        AQNumber = CVErr(xlValue)
    End If

End Function
```